# Star pattern is not executing

Tags: c

I am printing a star pattern of 100 asterisks using while loop, in which a new line has to be printed after every 10 asterisks, that makes it 10 lines of 10 asterisks. However, my conditions in loops are not working I guess.

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(
{
    int i = 1, rem, j = 0;
    char str = 'x';
    while (i <= 100)
    {
        printf("%c", str);
        while (j * 10 <= 100)
        {
            printf("\n");
            j++;
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need `j`. It is only throwing confusion into the program. Try to write the program with only `i` (no `j`, no `rem`)

Comment: Another way to think about it: What are the values of `i` that require a newline to be printed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way it will work

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
  int i=1,rem,j=0;
  char str='*';
  while(i<=10)
  {
    j = 0;
    while(j*10<100)
    {
      printf("%c",str);
      j++;
    }
    printf("\n");
    i++;
  }
}
```

Or just reduce the code to this

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
  for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
    printf("*");
    if (i % 10 == 0) // if i / 10 reamainder is 0 -> every 10th iteration
      printf("\n");
  }
}
```

Comment: There is quite few thing does not make sense in that code, just showed the "try to be minimal" change need to make it work anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Right now you have a loop from from 1 to 100, and one from 0 to 10 (since `j*10<=100` is just `j<=10`). That means the body of the inner loop is run (100-1+1) * (10-0+1) = 1100 times, when you want just 100 stars.

You want to output 10 rows. And for each row, you want to output 10 columns. So you want two nested loops from 0 to 9, one of the rows, and one for the columns.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char ch = '*';
    int row = 0;
    while (row < 10) {
        int col = 0;
        while (col < 10) {
            printf("%c", ch);
            ++col;
        }

        printf("\n");
        ++row;
    }
}
```

The code would be cleaner if we wrote those while loops using the `for (;;)` syntax.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char ch = '*';
    for (int row = 0; row < 10; ++row) {
        for (int col = 0; col < 10; ++col) {
            printf("%c", ch);
        }

        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it is overcomplicated:

```
void print(int numstars, int linelen)
{
    for(int star = 0; star < numstars; star++)
    {
        if(!(star % linelen)) printf("\n");
        printf("*");
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

because you need to print CR only after printing `linelen` number of stars the modulo `%` is the best way to check it.

https://godbolt.org/z/Un7DYN